# Original source of typescript from compiled javascript and source map

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, typescript, source-maps

I havent used sourcemaps and typescript before, so please bear that in mind.

I have to work with a project which was compiled to single javascript file from multiple typescript files.

I have available these files:

```
lib.js (the compiled js code of the project)
lib.js.map (the source map of the lib.js)
lib.d.ts (the "header" of the lib.js before it was compiled)
```

So I tried to view the original source files (original .ts files) in a browser but they are all blank in chrome and firefox outputs this message in them:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /path/source/file/file.ts was not found on this server. </p>
</body></html>
```

Can I somehow view the original .ts files, the compiled lib.js file is huge (2MB+) and it is a nightmare to work with.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you sure the ts files are present on your web server and the web server serves ts files (some web servers will only serve certain file types). If you try to access the ts file from the web browser it should be accessible to you just as any other resource (js, html, image). If the browser cannot access the ts file in this way it will default back to showing you the javascript.

Comment: So this means that I have to have the original .ts files :[ ? Unfortunately I dont have them, is it somehow possible to generate them from the three files in my post?

Comment: Sorry there is no way (that I am aware of, and it's highly unlikely to exist) to generate ts from js, .d.ts, and js.map. The original source is not present in any of these. The *.js is just javascript without any ts goodness, the .d.ts only contains publicly accessible symbols, and the *.js.map only specifies how the js maps to a ts file, but does not contain the ts itself.

Answer (score 0):

See if the last line of you generate .js file is the path for your map file. The path must be relative if you use Chrome or Firefox. if the path is absolute you get a 404 error.
Change this:

//# sourceMappingURL:X;/path/AdvantageClientAD.js.map

To this:
//# sourceMappingURL:AdvantageClientAD.js.map

This work if your ts files are in the same project as the .js files are deployed. But not if you have your typescript files in other project.